# The argument type 'RxString' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I try to use the GetX framework in flutter for my project. but it shows the Error regarding RxString. whenever I try to use the Obx method to call the controller object inside a text widget or a other String parameter widget it shows the error

```
The argument type 'RxString' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
```

this is my controller class

```
var qrValue = "waiting".obs;

socket.on('event', (data) 
{
    var qr = data['final'];
    qrValue.value = qr;
    print(qrValue);
 }
```

this want to pass the data to generate the qrcode

```
Obx(() => QrImage(
data: _controller.qrValue,
version: QrVersions.auto,
size: 200.0,
 ),
 )),
```

when i pass the qrvalue to the argument it show the error

> The argument type 'RxString' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing directly the ***Rx*** to the *data* property of *QrImage*. You need to pass the value of the ***Rx***:

```
data: _controller.qrValue.value,
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to append `.value` every time you access the controller's `obs` variable, consider setting a separate getter for the `rx` variable in the `GetX` Controller.

Add `_` to the existing variable name, and let the getter replace the existing variable name.

```
//getXController

final _qrValue = "waiting".obs;
get qrValue => _qrValue.value; // use getter
```

```
//Widget 

Obx(() => QrImage(
  data: _controller.qrValue,
  version: QrVersions.auto,
  size: 200.0,
 ),
),
```